# websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 4008 (private use), reason = Rate limited

Tags: websocket, discord.py

I am using Discord.py for my bot and this error occurs:
`websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 4008 (private use), reason = Rate limited.`

It happens when I use this:

```py
while true:
  activity=discord.Game(name=f"some stuff")
  await client.change_presence(activity=activity, status=status)
```

It is in an async function, so it is not related to async/await usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its apparently because of how frequently your status changes, there is almost no delay which makes the discord API considers it as an API abuse.

You might wanna try adding a suitable delay for the changing status

```py
while true:
  activity=discord.Game(name=f"some stuff")
  await client.change_presence(activity=activity, status=status)
  await asyncio.sleep(20) #time in seconds
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, I fixed the problem myself but this can stay for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently found out that it is caused by the `while` loop that constantly updates and causes the server to rate-limit