# WebSocket is closing spamming console?

Tags: discord.py

I am receiving a message in my console that says 'WebSocket connection is closing'. This message keeps appearing and the only way to stop it is by restarting the bot. Can you help me understand what this message means and how to fix the issue? I'm not sure if the problem is related to excessive usage of bot commands or if the bot is keeping its WebSocket open for too long.

Comment: You are most likely encountering Rate-Limits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451354/websockets-exceptions-connectionclosed-websocket-connection-is-closed-code-4

Comment: How would I enable a command to stop ratelimits

Comment: You need to slow/stop loops of your api calls. You can use sleep() functions or just command.cooldown decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem multiple times, it is an automatic reconnect to the Discord's WebSocket, so your internet may have been down or very slow. I am not aware this functions because of heavy rate limits, but this isn't something to get worried about.

It looks like this and sends them 8 - 13 times

```
websocket connection is closing...
websocket connection is closing...
```

If it cannot attempt to reconnect by itself, it should send this error `unclosed client session`
[image]